# Wait method run until CCActionSequence finishes

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
-(void) gameplay
{
    if (actionhappen){
        CCActionSequence *mySeq = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[do,some,action]];
        [mySprite runAction:mySeq]; // it takes 3 seconds.
    }
    [self checkWinner];
}


-(void)checkWinner{
if (someoneWin){
    // I want to wait here until mySeq action finished
        [self showWinnerMessage];
    }
}
```

in this code

[self showWinnerMessage] runs before mySeq finished.

How can I wait until the mySprite action finished?

Sleep() seems to make everything sleep.

Comment: there are runblock/performselector actions, put one at the end of the sequence

Comment: Thanks LearnCocos2D I can use runblock/performselector though, runAction doesn't happen always. I have updated the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, @LearnCocos2D already answered this question in comments, but here is the code to do this:

```
-(void) gameplay
{
    if (actionhappen)
    {
        CCActionCallFunc *checkWinner =
          [CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(checkWinner)];

        CCActionSequence *mySeq =
          [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[do,some,action, checkWinner]]; //note checkWinner

        [mySprite runAction:mySeq]; // it takes 3 seconds.
    }
    else
    {
        // in this case call the func directly
        [self checkWinner];
    }
}

-(void)checkWinner
{
    if (someoneWin)
    {
        // I want to wait here until mySeq action finished
        [self showWinnerMessage];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is quite good and useful for beginner. However,there is one condition, 'My CCActionSequencs is not excuted always' I have changed the code in article.

Comment: It is easy to update the code. I've updated answer, but you should've figured this yourself. You had the code which calls `checkWinner` without waiting for sequence to finish. I've pasted the code to wait for the sequence to finish. You should just use one depending on `actionhappen` flag and voila :)

Comment: Thanks alot You make my problem simple. thanks very much